# ESC opens windows window randomly

Tags: windows, keyboard

So I have been googling around and found this question:

[Why does the Start Menu open when I push escape in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/175627/why-does-the-start-menu-open-when-i-push-escape-in-windows-7)

Even though this question matches my problem, it does not fix my problem.

The problem I am having is that out of nowhere (sometimes it takes several hours, sometimes several minutes) the ESC button opens the windows window. Everyone keeps saying my control button is stuck but even after clicking it multiple times it does not fix it. Unplugging does not work and even buying a new keyboard and reinstalling a brand new windows 10 pro does not fix it.

Everyone just keeps saying I have to buy a brand new keyboard but that does not fix it either. This only started happening a month back or so. So could it be a windows bug?

I am on Windows 10 Pro 64bit and am using a brand new Corsair K65.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run OSK (aka The On-Screen Keyboard) and it will show you if Windows thinks the ctrl key is held down.

Comment: Well if you reinstalled Windows it is NOT a software (Windows) issue

Comment: Since I asked this question I have reinstalled windows, installed a new SSD (m.2 samsung 960 evo) and also bought a new keyboard, but it still comes up. I get very frustrated when this happends because the only fix is to completely restart the computer. This does not take a very long time but if you have to do it 6x in an hour it gets very annoying. I have also completely cleaned the pc inside and out. Getting rid of all the dust i could get off of it. But that also did not help.

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing a bug introduced by the Corsair device management software iCUE.

I created an account just to post this, since I've been following this thread (as well as a few others) since I first experienced the issue with iCUE causing issues with my Esc key.

I was finally able to resolve this by simply creating a custom rebind using iCUE to force the Esc key to rebind itself as the Esc Key. Sounds kind of silly and obvious... but it worked. Whatever bug iCUE has can be bypassed by using iCUE to rebind the Esc key to itself. Hope this helps!